# Check which face of a rectangular prism is colliding

Tags: 3d, collision-detection, game-physics, physics, collision

I am making a 3D physics engine with simple rectangular prism collisions, with no rotation.

Right now, I am doing collision very simply: (see [this website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection) for a nice graphic and more info)

```
let a and b be rectangular prisms
collide if:
   (min x of a <= max x of b AND max x of a >= min x of b) AND
   (min y of a <= max y of b AND max y of a >= min y of b) AND
   (min z of a <= max z of b AND max z of a >= min z of b)
```

This works well, but I need to know which surface the rectangles collided on to figure out how to bounce.

**Is there a formula to detect which face two rectangular prisms collided on?**

Answer (score 0):

If two rectangular prisms collide (i.e. intersect), it would be ambiguous as to which faces caused the collision:
[image]

You would need to know the vectors of the objects in order to determine the faces.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I realized that the face that caused the collision would be the face with the least intersection.

This is because after the other two axes are set, when trying to make the last axis overlap, it will stop before they can get closer than touching.

Therefore, the axis where `a max == b min` is the axis where the face is.
Checking which is up or down/left or right is as simple as checking if one object is above or below/left or right of the other object.

Of course, this solution will only work for my scenario with no rotation.